# Group annotations with same name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, annotations, mkmapview

I'm currently developing an iOS app which shows realtime data, now I receive 33,265 timingpoints from the API, which are all stops. So stops on opposite sides of the street are counted as 2, bus stations which have multiple platforms are also counted as many times as there are platforms.

Now, this is confusing on a map. You'd want all data for example a bus station on one screen and don't browse past 10 platforms to get the bus you'd like to take. So how can I group these annotation, which have the same name, and often are near or overlapping each other?

You can find an example of the JSON results from the API here: http://pastebin.com/RiKS4G0Q

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new entity `Location` and have a to-one relationship to each stop (reverse is to-many, of course). Now one stop can share a location and you can present the dat in an appropriate way.  During import, you could decide to create a new location if the coordinates are close enough to each other (and maybe the stop names correspond).

Comment: That would mean importing it into Core Data or something? Might make things quicker. Do need to think about how to do an update because new datasets are added frequently, and stops change as well.